# sql update only the oldest of a many-to-one association

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the tables in MySQL 5.0:

```
clients
=======
id  int

users
=====
id         int
client_id  int
is_primary tinyint
```

A client can have many users.  I want to update users.is_primary = 1 for only the smallest users.id per users.client_id

For example, given these users:

```
users
id   client_id    is_primary
============================
1    1            0
2    1            0
3    2            0
4    2            0
5    3            0
```

I want to end up with:

```
users
id   client_id    is_primary
============================
1    1            1
2    1            0
3    2            1
4    2            0
5    3            1
```

Is there a way to write an update statement to do so?

Comment: Why does the row `id = 5` have `is_primary = 1`? This client, `client_id = 1`, has already got one primary user.

Comment: MySQL 5.0, updated the question.

Comment: @Andriy: I need for the first user per client to be marked as is_primary=1 whether they are the only user for that client or not.

Comment: But `id = 5` is not the first user for client 1, however `id = 1` is and it's marked as such.

Comment: @Andriy: oops, you're right, it should have been 3.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update users 
set is_primary = 1
where id in (select * from (select min(id) from users group by client_id) as t)
```

Comment: I think you should alias the `min(id)` column. Or will MySQL allow it to go unaliased?

Comment: @Andriy M: no, it's not necessary.

Comment: +1: But [MySQL UPDATE supports JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), which oddly doesn't run foul of the MySQL 1093 error

Comment: @ OMG Ponies. You're right. I've just modified Omriko's query to run without that error. I prefer Andriy M's solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you should be able to use the join like this:

```
UPDATE users
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    FROM users
    GROUP BY client_id
  ) m ON users.id = m.id
SET users.is_primary = 1
```